# laravel dompdf export not export all content of my view

Tags: laravel, pdf, export, dompdf

I'm currently using Laravel 9, laravel dompdf package for export my file, this the pdf file I got, no content at all. The data I pass did not get displayed in the PDF.

[image]

But when I just open it as view, the data pass properly and the css work nice. This is how it looks like:

[image]

Here is my code on the view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
     
      </head>
    
      <style>
        * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
    }
    body {
      background:#DDD;
        
    }
    div.container {
      max-width: 1350px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      overflow: hidden
    }
    .upcoming {
      font-size: 45px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      border-left: 14px solid rgba(255, 235, 59, 0.78);
      padding-left: 12px;
      margin: 18px 8px;
    }
    .container .item {
      width: 48%;
      float: left;
      padding: 0 20px;
      background: #fff;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin: 10px
    }
    .container .item-right, .container .item-left {
      float: left;
      padding: 20px 
    }
    .container .item-right {
      padding: 79px 0px;
      margin-right: 20px;
      width: 25%;
      position: relative;
      height: 286px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .container .item-right .up-border, .container .item-right .down-border {
        padding: 14px 15px;
        background-color: #ddd;
        border-radius: 50%;
        position: absolute
    }
    .container .item-right .up-border {
      top: -8px;
      right: -35px;
    }
    .container .item-right .down-border {
      bottom: -13px;
      right: -35px;
    }
    .container .item-right .num {
      font-size: 50px;
      color: #111
    }
    .container .item-right .day, .container .item-left .event {
      color: #555;
      font-size: 15px;
      margin-bottom: 9px;
    }
    .container .item-right .day {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 25px;
    }
    .container .item-left {
      width: 71%;
      padding: 34px 0px 19px 46px;
      border-left: 3px dotted #999;
    } 
    .container .item-left .title {
      color: #111;
      font-size: 34px;
      margin-bottom: 12px
    }
    .container .item-left .sce {
      margin-top: 5px;
      display: block
    }
    .container .item-left .sce .icon, .container .item-left .sce p,
    .container .item-left .loc .icon, .container .item-left .loc p{
        float: left;
        word-spacing: 5px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        color: #888;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .container .item-left .sce .icon, .container .item-left .loc .icon {
      margin-right: 10px;
      font-size: 20px;
      color: #666
    }
    .container .item-left .loc {display: block}
    .fix {clear: both}
    .container .item .tickets, .booked, .cancel{
        color: #fff;
        padding: 6px 14px;
        float: right;
        margin-top: 10px;
        font-size: 18px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer
    }
    .container .item .tickets {background: #777}
    .container .item .booked {background: #3D71E9}
    .container .item .cancel {background: #DF5454}
    .linethrough {text-decoration: line-through}

      </style>

    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="upcoming">Event Tickets</h1>
            @php ($i=1)

            @foreach ($tickets as $key=> $ticket)
            <div class="item">
              <div class="item-right">
                <h2 class="num"> {{ $ticket->ticket_no }}</h2>
                <p class="day">Ticket No.</p>
                <span class="up-border"></span>
                <span class="down-border"></span>
              </div> <!-- end item-right -->
              
              <div class="item-left">
                <p class="event">{{ $ticket->GiftGiving->name }}</p>
                <h2 class="title">{{ $ticket->name }}</h2>
                
                <div class="sce">
               
                  <p>{{Carbon\Carbon::parse($ticket->GiftGiving->start_at )->isoFormat('LL') }}<br/> {{   Carbon\Carbon::parse($ticket->GiftGiving->start_at )->isoFormat('h:mm A') }}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="fix"></div>
                <div class="loc">
           
                  <p>{{ $ticket->GiftGiving->venue }}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="fix"></div>
                <button class="booked">Batch No. {{ $ticket->GiftGiving->batch_no}}</button>
              </div> <!-- end item-right -->
            </div> <!-- end item -->

                 <!--Set limitation of printing only 5 ticket per page-->
                 @if ($i % 6 === 0)
                 <div style="page-break-after: always;"></div>
                 @endif
            
             @php ($i++)
         @endforeach
          </div>
        


    </body>
</html>
```

```
Controller
```

```
public function GenerateTicket($code)
{
    # Retrieve the records using $code
    $GiftGiving = GiftGiving::where('code', $code)->firstOrFail();
    $tickets = GiftGivingBeneficiary::where('gift_giving_id', $GiftGiving->id)->get();

    # Users can only access their own charity's records
    if ($GiftGiving->charitable_organization_id == Auth::user()->charitable_organization_id) {

        # Must have at least one beneficiary before generating tickets
        if ($tickets->count() < 1) {
            $toastr = array(
                'message' => 'Gift Giving must have at least one (1) beneficiary first before generating tickets',
                'alert-type' => 'error'
            );

            return redirect()->back()->with($toastr);
        }

        # Retrieve the last batch no. from the gift giving.
        $batch_no = $GiftGiving->batch_no;

        # Increment Batch no. by +1
        $GiftGiving->update([
            'last_downloaded_by' => Auth::id(),
            'batch_no' => $batch_no + 1,
        ]);


        # Audit Logs Creation
        $log = new AuditLog;
        $log->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $log->action_type = 'GENERATE PDF';
        $log->charitable_organization_id = Auth::user()->charitable_organization_id;
        $log->table_name = 'Gift Giving';
        $log->record_id = $GiftGiving->code;
        $log->action = 'Charity Admin generated tickets for the Gift Giving [' . $GiftGiving->name . '] with batch no. ' . $GiftGiving->batch_no . '.';
        $log->performed_at = Carbon::now();
        $log->save();


        # Send Notification to each user in their Charitable Organizations
        $users = User::where('charitable_organization_id', Auth::user()->charitable_organization_id)->where('status', 'Active')->get();

        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $notif = new Notification;
            $notif->code = Str::uuid()->toString();
            $notif->user_id = $user->id;
            $notif->category = 'Gift Giving';
            $notif->subject = 'Generated Tickets';
            $notif->message = Auth::user()->role . ' ' . Auth::user()->info->first_name . ' ' .
                Auth::user()->info->last_name . ' has generated tickets for [' . $GiftGiving->name . '] with batch no. ' .
                $GiftGiving->batch_no . '.';
            $notif->icon = 'mdi mdi-ticket';
            $notif->color = 'info';
            $notif->created_at = Carbon::now();
            $notif->save();
        }
        
        // return view('charity.gifts.generate_ticket', compact('tickets'));
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('charity.gifts.generate_ticket', compact('tickets'));
        
        return $pdf->download($GiftGiving->name . ' - No. ' . $GiftGiving->batch_no . '.pdf');
    } else {

        $toastr = array(
            'message' => 'Users can only access their own charity records.',
            'alert-type' => 'error'
        );

        return redirect()->back()->with($toastr);
    }
}
```

Hope somebody can point out what I missed, thank you in advance. All suggestions/answers are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

dompdf is really picky about CSS and styles... but first, you should always put your `<style>` tags inside the `<head>` tag of the document. Without putting it there, there will be inconsistencies in how different browsers render the content, and that includes headless systems and domPDF.

So put your `<style>` tag in the `<head>` tags, and see if that helps resolve the issue, and if not, try converting your styles to tables with styling, as dompdf seems to do better with tables than divs.

Answer (score 0):

you should care about syntax:

```
@php $i = 1; @endphp 
@php $i++; @endphp
```